# What is Image Gallery's best alternative in Android Jelly Bean?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

```
This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.
```

I tried to browse answers from previous questions in stackoverflow. I found out some alternatives:

- http://pastebin.com/FWyYTt4D
- https://github.com/search?q=gallery&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Gallery has been depreciated since since API level 16 until Jelly Bean. What is the new alternatives for this feature? Any gallery like features released in 4.2?

Comment: The new alternatives are the ones you found by searching StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ MarsAtomic. Well I am inlove with Universal-Image-Loader as it deals a lot with images and caching.

Here's the great library [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)